# Detect what type of event triggered a UIControl's action

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uicontrol

I have a custom `UIControl` subclass with an action method callback.  I want to display the value of the control element on a `UILabel`  while it is being adjusted, and then I want the label to become hidden when the user stops adjusting the control.

Therefore, I have connected the action for both `UIControlEventValueChanged` and `UIControlEventTouchUpInside`.  Both successfully invoke my action method.  However, to do different things in this method based on the action I need to know which event triggered the method.  How can I do this?  I've looked through `UIControl` and don't see an obvious property. `state` seems to return `1` for both actions.

So something like this:

```
    - (void)handleSlider1:(CustomSlider*)sender {

        if (sender.state == UIControlEventValueChanged) {
            // code
        } else {
            // different code
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can distinguish the two events pretty easily by connecting them each to separate `IBAction`s. Each new action then would call your single handler, passing the appropriate `UIControlEvent` value along:

```
- (IBAction)sliderValueChanged:(CustomSlider *)slider
{
    [self handleSlider1:slider forEvent:UIControlEventValueChanged];   
}

- (IBAction)sliderValueChanged:(CustomSlider *)slider
{
    [self handleSlider1:slider forEvent:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];   
}

- (void)handleSlider1:(CustomSlider *)sender forEvent:(UIControlEvents)event
{
    if (event == UIControlEventValueChanged)
    //...
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you think I need an `IBAction`.  I am not using any IB features.  Just Code.

What I winded up doing was to send the action `UIControlEventTouchCancel` in my `UIControl` subclasses's `endTrackingWithTouch:` method.  On top of that (and adding to the complexity), I set my control's main value to `-1` as a sentinel to my viewController that this action was `UIControlEventTouchCancel`.  The reason for the `-1` is exactly because when a control event triggers an action method it does not appear to send information to identify which control event it was.

Comment: You can use this technique regardless of whether they are IBActions.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the same method to handle both events then you can check the **highlighted** property of the control:

```
if (sender.highlighted) {
   // slider is changing value (value changed)
} else {
   // slider has stopped changing value (touch up inside)
}
```

Alternatively, you could simply create two separate action methods and connect each event to the required method.

Comment: that wasn't what i asked.  the question was about how to detect what kind of action was sent.

Comment: as far as using one callback for multiple `UIControl`'s I simply use `.tag` = 1,2,3,4...